# Prove that the trace of a dyad uv is the dot product of u and v

Tags: tensors

$$
I'm\quad trying\quad to\quad demonstrate\quad that\quad the\quad trace\quad of\quad a\quad dyad\quad (tensor\quad product)\quad is\\ equal\quad to\quad the\quad dot\quad product\quad of\quad those\quad vectors\\ tr(\underline { u } \otimes \underline { v } )=\underline { u } \cdot \underline { v } \\ \underline { u } \quad and\quad \underline { v } \quad are\quad vectors\quad in\quad V,\quad euclidean\quad orthonormal\quad basis\quad vectors\quad \underline { e_{ i } } \\ This\quad is\quad the\quad way\quad I'm\quad doing\quad this\quad \\ Let\quad [a,b,c]=\quad a\cdot \quad (b\quad \times \quad c)\quad ,\quad a,b,c\quad arbitrary\quad vectors\quad in\quad V\\ Then\quad [a\quad b\quad c]tr(\underline { u } \otimes \underline { v } )=\quad [(\underline { u } \otimes \underline { v } )a,b,c]+[a,(\underline { u } \otimes \underline { v } )b,c]+[a,b,(\underline { u } \otimes \underline { v } )c]\\ So\quad ,\quad (a\cdot v)[\underline { u } ,b,c]+(b\cdot v)[a,\underline { u } ,c]+(c\cdot v)[a,b,\underline { u } ]\\ Then,\quad I\quad don't\quad really\quad know\quad what\quad to\quad do.\\ I'm\quad using\quad the\quad fact\quad that\quad the\quad first\quad invariant\quad of\quad a\quad tensor\quad T\quad is\quad the\quad trace\quad Tii.\\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ 
$$

Comment: Just use the fact that $u\otimes v(w) = \langle u, w\rangle v$. Now compute $\sum \langle u\otimes v(e_i), e_i\rangle$ where $\{e_i\}$ is the standard basis.

Comment: w is just an arbitrary vector. The notation I'm using , I think , it's correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Solution using box or scalar product.]

```
   Solution using box or scalar product.
```

Answer (score 1):

There are, obviously, abstract arguments you can give. But why not write $u$ and $v$ in terms of their coordinates with respect to the orthonormal basis $\{e_i\}$? Then the dyadic product is the square matrix with entries $u_iv_j$, and the sum of the diagonal entries is $\sum u_iv_i= u\cdot v$.

Comment: That's correct but I was trying to use those box products 
$$ \quad [a,\quad b,\quad c]
$$
to solve this. Any idea on how to do it?

Comment: So you're trying to do an argument in $\mathbb R^3$ only?

Comment: Yes, I'm limited to R3
@TedShrifin